# How do you remove words from Swype's dictionary?

Tags: keyboard, settings, swype

I know how to remove words from Swype's user dictionary. I want to know how to remove words from Swype's built-in dictionary. I get very frustrated with all these random words that I know I'll never use! I can't tell you how many times I've had the word "Getty" show up instead of the word "get".

If there is really no way of removing words from Swype's built-in dictionary I'll probably need to find an alternative. That's probably another question though.

Answer (score 3):

Swype uses a separate dictionary. You can access the settings for both from within the system settings:

From the homescreen, open *settings → language & keyboard*

- for Swype continue: *Swype → Personal dictionary*
- for the default keyboard: *My dictionary*

There you can edit/add/remove words from your user dictionary.

Comment: This no longer works for Swype 1.3

Comment: And this is the user dictionary, not the built-in dictionary. I, too, would like to remove words like "Getty" that I would never ever type.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this on Froyo, I can remove the unwanted Swype words by:
1. Swype the word.
2. Select that word.
3. Hit the 'Swype' key.
4. You will get a confirmation to delete the word from Swype dictionary.

On latest android version, you get a list of words on the top of the keyboard.
If the unwanted word comes on top, long tap it.
You will get an option to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Also I had this problem, and I talked to the Samsung through Facebook. I was told to clear the cache partition, and I think it worked. The unwanted words I removed don't appear to be coming back.